# MVC4 One view with multiple forms, fill view with data from first submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, viewmodel

I'm using MVC4 Razor and I'm trying to make a very specific Create page.

In this page, I firstly want to upload a password protected file, hence the first submit form.
I redirected this submit to an action method "upload" with a ViewModel like this:

```
public class UploadViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string filePath { get; set; }
}
```

And View:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.UploadViewModel

@{
     ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
         <legend>File</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.file)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.file, new { type = "file" })
            @*<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.file)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

In the upload action I verify the password. If the password is correct, I extract data from the file and pass it to another ViewModel.

Upload action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Upload(UploadViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //process file, load CreateViewModel and save file locally
    }

    return View("Create", newModel);
}
```

New ViewModel:

```
public class CreateViewModel
{
    public string fullname { get; set; }
    public string company { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

I want to pass the CreateViewModel to the same Create view where the forms are filled with the extracted data and where the user gets the opportunity to verify the data. If all the data is correct, he will then submit it (hence second form) and create a new file entry.

This is where I got stuck, how can I make a view that accepts two ViewModels? Or is there any other way to solve my problem? And how can I save the values from the first ViewModel temporarily to push them to db all together in the Create action?

### UPDATE

I ended up separating these views and the viewmodels for simplicity...
I got it working with combining the viewmodels as well but that caused some problems with storing the file itself.

Sorry for the late update but as this is a project I can only work on at work as a side project, I don't have that much time.

Comment: Couldn't you just convert them into one? Or have a viewmodel that contains the other one? public class UploadViewModel{ ... public CreateViewModel CreateViewModel { get; set; } ... } Then you're saving the data across both views and can eventually push it to the db together in the end.

Comment: I've thought of that but wouldn't it be inefficient to push a file back to the view to resubmit it again afterwards? I also have no idea how to show a file in a view.

Comment: I don't think its inefficient to the point where it's going to have any detrimental effects on your application. The easiest way is just going to be to create a ViewModel that takes the properties from the Upload/Create models above.

Comment: Okay, I will try this and I'll keep you posted! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing that comes to my mind is to create a ViewModel of the two ViewModels. When you postback the first time, you will have the data from the first ViewModel, but the second ViewModel will be empty.

In order to store the values from the first ViewModel, after you return from your first postback to the view, you could store the values in hidden fields. In this way, when you postback the second time, the values will be available for both the first and second ViewModel.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try this combined with Jon La Marr's solution and I'll keep you posted.